# NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy

The integration is:

```
NIntegrate[-0.17116940940118283` + 1/(
  9.736942322213501` + 7.789553857770802` Cos[q]) + (
  0.02866566930866079` (0.5` + 1.` Cos[q]) Sin[
    q] (-3.0095696738628313` Sqrt[1.25` + 1.` Cos[q]]
       Cos[0.` + ArcTan[(0.5` Sin[q])/(-1 - 0.5` Cos[q])]] + 
     1.` Sin[q]))/(
  0.9772727272727273` + 1.` Cos[q] - 0.045454545454545456` Cos[2 q] - 
   0.09090909090909091` Cos[3 q]) + ((0.35586923225834494` + 
     0.5931153870972414` Cos[q] + 0.11862307741944829` Cos[2 q]) Sin[
    0.` + ArcTan[(0.5` Sin[q])/(-1 - 0.5` Cos[q])]])/((1.75` + 
     1.` Cos[q] - 0.5` Cos[2 q])^(3/2) Sqrt[
   1 - (1.` Sin[q]^2)/(
    1.75` + 1.` Cos[q] - 0.5000000000000001` Cos[2 q])]), {q, -Pi, 
  Pi}]
```

. Error message is

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in q near {q} = {-3.14159254089972008785892145083358745552559732061581598827615380287}. NIntegrate obtained -1.249*10^-16 and 4.588053980254483`*^-13 for the integral and error estimates.**

How to get the real integration value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve the problem of calculating the value of an integral that is actually $0$, you can set a lower `AccuracyGoal` than the default value (`Infinity`), as [Andrew Moylan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/31/andrew-moylan) mentioned [in this previous question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41297/27951): "When the true value of the integral is zero, the default `PrecisionGoal` can never be satisfied. You need to set a finite `AccuracyGoal` in such cases".

With your integrand defined as `expr` for clarity, the following returns no errors:

```
NIntegrate[expr, {q, -Pi, Pi}, AccuracyGoal -> 10]

(* Out: 1.66533*10^-16 *)
```

---

see also:

- [Numerical integration is taking too long whenever the answer is zero](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223008/27951)
- [Error to converge NIntegrate with FindRoot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176629/27951)
- [Problem with Integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223021/27951)

Answer (score 4):

Also `NDSolve` as a workaround evaluates to `~0`

```
expr = -0.17116940940118283` +1/(9.736942322213501` +7.789553857770802` Cos[q]) + (0.02866566930866079` (0.5` + 1.` Cos[q]) Sin[q] (-3.0095696738628313` Sqrt[1.25` + 1.` Cos[q]] Cos[0.` + ArcTan[(0.5` Sin[q])/(-1 - 0.5` Cos[q])]] +1.` Sin[q]))/(0.9772727272727273` + 1.` Cos[q] -0.045454545454545456` Cos[2 q] -0.09090909090909091` Cos[3 q]) + ((0.35586923225834494` +0.5931153870972414` Cos[q] +0.11862307741944829` Cos[2 q]) Sin[0.` + ArcTan[(0.5` Sin[q])/(-1 - 0.5` Cos[q])]])/((1.75` +1.` Cos[q] - 0.5` Cos[2 q])^(3/2) Sqrt[1 - (1.` Sin[q]^2)/(1.75` + 1.` Cos[q] -0.5000000000000001` Cos[2 q])]) 
// Rationalize;

NDSolveValue[{int'[q] == expr, int[-Pi] == 0}, int[Pi], {q, -Pi, Pi},AccuracyGoal -> 15]
(*-3.79922*10^-8*)
```

indicates a zero integral value!

Comment: Could you please kindly explain, why `NDSolve` is better than `NIntegrate`?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Not better, perhaps the integration routines inside NDSolve are a little bit more robust? In any case `NDSolve` evaluates without error message.

Comment: `Rationalize` without the second argument does not fully rationalize the expression. Use `expr // Rationalize[#, 0]& // Simplify` then `NDSolveValue[{int'[q] == expr, int[-Pi] == 0}, int[Pi], {q, -Pi, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 40]`

Comment: `NDSolve` seems more "robust" here because the (local) `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` are around 8, whereas for `NIntegrate`, the (global) goals are about 8 and `Infinity` respectively. (That's why the `NDSolve` result has an accuracy of only ~7.4).

Answer (score 3):

NIntegrate may have problems if the true value of the integral is zero. The error message quotes this as possible reason for the convergence problem.
As a workaround you could add 1 to the integrand and subtract 2Pi in the end like

```
NIntegrate[-0.17116940940118283 + 
1/(9.736942322213501 + 7.789553857770802*Cos[q]) + 
   (0.02866566930866079*(0.5 + 1.*Cos[q])*
  Sin[q]*(-3.0095696738628313*Sqrt[1.25 + 1.*Cos[q]]*
     Cos[0. + ArcTan[(0.5*Sin[q])/(-1 - 0.5*Cos[q])]] + 
           1.*Sin[q]))/(0.9772727272727273 + 1.*Cos[q] - 
  0.045454545454545456*Cos[2*q] - 
  0.09090909090909091*Cos[3*q]) + 
   ((0.35586923225834494 + 0.5931153870972414*Cos[q] + 
    0.11862307741944829*Cos[2*q])*
  Sin[0. + ArcTan[(0.5*Sin[q])/(-1 - 0.5*Cos[q])]])/
     ((1.75 + 1.*Cos[q] - 0.5*Cos[2*q])^(3/2)*
  Sqrt[1 - (1.*Sin[q]^2)/(1.75 + 1.*Cos[q] - 
       0.5000000000000001*Cos[2*q])]) + 1, {q, -Pi, Pi}] - 2*Pi
```

Edit:
I rationalized all numbers and now WorkingPrecision can be set to a higher value:

```
NIntegrate[-(17116940940118283/100000000000000000) + 
 1/(9736942322213501/
  1000000000000000 + (7789553857770802/1000000000000000)*Cos[q]) + 
 ((2866566930866079/100000000000000000)*(1/2 + Cos[q])*Sin[q]*
      ((-(30095696738628313/10000000000000000))*Sqrt[5/4 + Cos[q]]*
           Cos[ArcTan[((1/2)*Sin[q])/(-1 - (1/2)*Cos[q])]] + 
   Sin[q]))/
   (43/44 + Cos[q] - (1/22)*Cos[2*q] - (1/11)*Cos[3*q]) + 
 ((35586923225834494/
    100000000000000000 + (5931153870972414/10000000000000000)*
           Cos[q] + (11862307741944829/100000000000000000)*
    Cos[2*q])*
      Sin[ArcTan[((1/2)*Sin[q])/(-1 - (1/2)*Cos[q])]])/
   ((7/4 + Cos[q] - (1/2)*Cos[2*q])^(3/2)*
   Sqrt[1 - Sin[q]^2/(7/4 + Cos[q] - (1/2)*Cos[2*q])]), {q, -Pi, Pi}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

Now the precision of the calculation should be higher (15 digits ?) and it completes without complaint.
So the real value of the integral as given by the OP is

```
3.28296365*10^-16
```

Answer (score 2):

I should probably change what I say up front:

> The full error message, perhaps surprisingly, is saying there is nothing to worry about, and no fix is needed.

This is the opposite of most people's reactions to error messages, including mine, especially when the message leads with the word "failed."
The point is to think about this part of the error message:

> `NIntegrate` obtained `-1.24910*^-16` and `4.588053980254483*^-13` for the integral and error estimates.

That means `NIntegrate` calculated the integral to be in the interval

```
{-4.586804880254483`*^-13, 4.589303080254483`*^-13}
```

Now, ***is that a good enough answer?***

Probably, it is, unless you believe (for other reasons, say, based on what the value is supposed to represent) that the integral is nonzero and smaller than `10^-13`.  Probably you don't need to do anything; just accept the answer. On the other hand, if an uncertainty of `4.6*10^-13` is unacceptable, then none of the methods discussed below fix that; they just hide the problem.

The OP's method is better than the `NDSolve` method, which lies well outside this interval and corresponds to its `AccuracyGoal` of about `8`.

The OP's method is better than the `NIntegrate` answer obtained by integrating `1 + integrand` and subtracting `2 Pi` for somewhat technical reasons:  The default precision goal is about `6`, which means that the error in the value the integral is bounded by `2 Pi 10*^-6`, which is much greater than `4.6*10^-13`.  Further, while the value of the integral in this method (minus `2 Pi`) lies inside the interval, it is much larger than the value of the OP's integral.

The OP's method is better than lowering `AccuracyGoal`.  The setting [`AccuracyGoal -> a`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139311/4999) means roughly that if the absolute error is less than `10^-a`, `NIntegrate` will accept the result.  By lowering `AccuracyGoal`, you are actually telling `NIntegrate` to accept a worse result. A good reason to do this is given in one of the answers @MarcoB linked: A lower setting speeds up `NIntegrate` when the integral is (nearly) zero, because it is easier to compute a less accurate result.

There is nothing very wrong in these other methods.  Unless you need more than 8 decimal places of accuracy, which almost certainly is not the case here, they are fine but no better than the OP's method. The error message in this case in fact indicates how ***good*** the answer is. In other cases, it might indicate how bad the answer could be.

Comment: the result I get for `integrand +1`is `-6.838973831690964*^-14`, well within the error interval of (+-) 4*10^-13

Comment: @Andreas That is what said: "while the value of the integral (minus 2 Pi) lies inside the interval,"

Comment: It's somewhat irrelevant since the error-bound interval estimated by `NIntegrate` in the `1 + integrand` approach is ``{-6.620418321663166`*^-8, 6.620404643715502`*^-8}``, which is much larger.

Comment: where do you get +-6*10^-8 from

Comment: @Andreas The `PrecisionGoal` for a 1D `NIntegrate` is normally `6` (which I misremembered as `8`).  So the condition that must be met is that the error estimate needs to be lower than `2 Pi * 10^-6` = ±6*10^-6, not `2 Pi * 10^-8` as I was saying.